# Is there a way to use variables which are declared in HTML in HTML lines before their declaration?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I would like to use the rowData var which is declared in my second HTML line in line 1. For now I obviously get the "Property 'rowData' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'" error in line 1. rowData in the fourth line is working as expected. Is there a way to use a var which isn't declared yet? Something like a placeholder or something? I am using Angular (HTML and Typescript) with PrimeNG.

HTML:

```
...
<p-table selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect(rowData)>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" type="default" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
 <tr [pSelectableRow]="col">
  <td><icon (click)="openComponent(rowData)"></td>
...
```

Comment: There isn't but what's wrong with `onRowSelect($event.data)`?

Comment: When I do this and I try to read its value via console.log it just says undefined. Even tough I've used [value]="dataSource.data" onRowSelect($event.data) and onRowSelect($event.dataSource.data) dosent work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a kind of "placeholder" you can use it with an **EventEmitter** (import it from @angular/core) and it is called **$event**.

It is a slightly different construct, though. I will try to explain.

In your **Component** you declare an **@Output** and assign it an **EventEmitter** like this:

```js
@Output() setActiveItem = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

And listen e.g. bind it to another function, wich will take the **$event** in your Template like this:

```html
<your-component (setActiveItem)="someOtherFunction($event)"></your-component>
```

Now you can call the emitter like this (note that we call the **emit**-method on the emitter):

```html
<li (click)=setActiveItem.emit(rowData)> whatever </li>
```

someOtherFunction will now receive the $event wich will carry your rowData or whatever you emit with it.

Hope this helps

Cheers Phil

Answer (score 0):

First option with $event :

```
<p-table selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
<ng-template pTemplate="body" type="default" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
 <tr [pSelectableRow]="col">
  <td><icon (click)="openComponent(rowData)"></td>
```

Second option with [(selection)] :

```
<p-table selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedRow" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect()">
<ng-template pTemplate="body" type="default" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
 <tr [pSelectableRow]="col">
  <td><icon (click)="openComponent(rowData)"></td>
```

And in your function onRowSelect, you need to use variable this.selectedRow